# How to Mock Java Optional Class in Groovy class which Extends Spock Specification

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, groovy, spock

I have a very simple Spring Rest service. Below is my ServiceImpl Class in Java :-

1. Service Impl Class =>

   ```
   @AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = (@__(@Autowired)))
   public Class ServiceImpl implements ServiceClass {


       private ServiceRepository repo;
       private MapstructRequestMapper1 mapper1;


       private Optional<Pojo1> pojo1;

       @Override
       public Optional<Pojo1> getSomething(Pojo2 pojo2, String someString){ return repository.findById(Id)};

       @Override
       public SomeResponse createSomething(Pojo2 pojo2, String someString){

           pojo1 = getSomething(someString); //This Returns an Optional object.

           if(pojo1.ifPresent(pojo1-> {

                   //set something with pojo1's attributes and then do something.

           });
           )

       }

   }
   ```
2. Impltest class:- (uses Groovy + Spock Specification)

```
    def ref = Mock(Servicerepo)
    def mapperRef1 = Mock(MapstructRequestMapper1)
    //This is where I am stuck

    def requestTestObj = Mock(Pojo1)

    def service = new ServiceImpl(ref,mapperRef1, requestTestObj) //This is where it fails.

    def "myTest - some bla" () {

    }


}
```

**ERROR** => if if I tried **def requestTestObj = Mock(Pojo1) as Optional** it gives me following 2 errors:-

1. ***Class cannot be casted.***
2. if without ***"as Optional"*** it gives me "***No Matching Constructor in the ImplTestclass***".

How do we handle this ? DB used here is Mongo

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mock class `Optional` directly by conventional means because the class is final and Spock mocks are based on dynamic proxies, i.e. sub-classing. But how about mocking `Pojo1` and wrapping it into an `Optional`?

```groovy
def requestTestObj = Mock(Pojo1)
def service = new ServiceImpl(ref, mapperRef1, Optional.of(requestTestObj))
```

As usual, you can stub the POJO's methods, verify that certain methods have been called so many times and so forth.